# Matrix, norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose A is an invertible matrix.

How do I show $  |{Av}| \geq \frac{|v|}{det A^{-1}} $ ?

[image]

Comment: I have improved the question.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question Your question leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, because it doesn't hold. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}$, $v=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. Please look at the lemma that I updated in the question. Is it wrong or am I reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, you are reading it incorrectly. $\lVert A^{-1}\rVert$ is the operator norm of the matrix $A^{-1}$.

Comment: I see. This is a question about matrix norms.